# Why do I keep getting this error during my trajectory calculation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make trajectory calculations, and I know, what y value it will have at landing (that -0.995). I'm trying to calculate how much time will it take to fall down to that height, so I can set the x value based on that.

I'm a 9th grader, we just learned about quadratic equations. So I tried to solve it, I think I did that right, but I keep getting the weird weird error, saying

> Rigidbody2D.position assign attempt for 'Spawner' is not valid. Input
> position is { NaN, -1.000000 }.
> UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D:set_position(Vector2) Spawner:Update() (at
> Assets/Spawner.cs:29)

So I get that it couldn't calculate the X value, but that's because when I made it write out the predicted time, it also said NaN, so I don't know what is the problem here, that's why I'm asking here.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner: MonoBehaviour
{
    float arriveTime;
    public GameObject player;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float predictedX = 1;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {


            arriveTime = (-1 * rb.velocity.y - Mathf.Sqrt(rb.velocity.y * rb.velocity.y - 4 * (Physics2D.gravity.y / 2 * -0.995f))) / Physics2D.gravity.y;
            predictedX = rb.position.x + arriveTime * rb.velocity.x;

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().position = new Vector2(predictedX, -1);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `Input position is { NaN, -1.000000 }.`

As soon as only one component of a calculation is `NaN` then any subsequent result will also return `NaN`.

So if `arriveTime` already is `NaN` then also `predictedX` will be `NaN` since `arriveTime` is involved in its calculation.

[`NaN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.nan) is usually the result for a **mathematically undefined** (for rational numbers) operation.

There are two places I can spot immediately in the calculation of `arriveTime` where this might happen:

- Possible division by `0` at the end for `/ Physics2D.gravity.y`.

  *This is a special case though and would only be `NaN` for `0/0` otherwise it would be either positive or negative infinity.*
- Possibly trying to take the `Mathf.Sqrt` of a **negative** value in the case that `rb.velocity.y * rb.velocity.y` is smaller than `4 * (Physics2D.gravity.y / 2 * -0.995f)`

---

You could check these cases e.g.

```
if(Physics2D.gravity.y == 0)
{
    // probably do nothing or sanatize the value to something else
    return;
}

var ySqr = rb.velocity.y * rb.velocity.y;
var subs = 4 * (Physics2D.gravity.y / 2 * -0.995f);

if(ySqr < subs)
{
    // do nothing or sanatize the value
    // e.g. you could use the Mathf.Abs value instead
    return;
}

arriveTime = (1 - rb.velocity.y - Mathf.Sqrt(ySqr - subs)) / Physics2D.gravity.y;
```

or you can also simply check afterwards for `NaN` after the calculations like e.g.

```
if(predictedX == float.NaN)
{
    // probably do nothing or sanatize the value to something else
    return;
}
```

---

As already mentioned in the code comments, most probably you would rather sanatize the value e.g. by using the absolute

```
arriveTime = (-1 * rb.velocity.y - Mathf.Sqrt(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y * rb.velocity.y - 4 * (Physics2D.gravity.y / 2 * -0.995f)))) / Physics2D.gravity.y;
```

since as mentioned it is unlikely that the issue is a division by `0` here.